# R: Using Expand.Grid() Based on Certain Conditions

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

**I have the following problem:**

- Imagine there are two coins being flipped twice - (e.g. maybe coin_1 flipped twice, maybe coin_1 flipped once and coin_2 flipped once, maybe coin_2 flipped twice)
- There are probabilities associated with selecting which coins are going to be flipped (i.e. p1 and 1-p1)
- The probability of a heads (success) from coin_1 is q1 and from coin_2 is q2 (note that q1 and q2 are independent and do not need to sum to 1)
- I want to list all combinations of : p1, 1-p1, q1, q2 . For example: (coin_1 = 1, coin_2 = 0) .... (coin_1 = 0.99, coin_2 = 0.01) .... (coin_1 = 0.01, coin_2 = 0.99) .... (coin_1 = 0, coin_2 = 1)
- For each of these combination, I want to list all 4 combinations that can arise from these probabilities (i.e. coin1,1 = HH, coin1,1 = HT, coin1,1 = TH, coin1,1 = TT, coin1,2 = HH, coin1,2 = HT, coin1,2 = TH, coin1,2 = TH, coin2,2 = HH, coin2,2 = HT, coin2,2 = TH, coin2,2 = TT)
- Then, I want to calculate the "likelihood" for these combinations (i.e. probability of selecting coins * probability of results )

**The final result would look something like this** (e.g. for a specific combination of selection probabilities, success probabilities and results - note that xyz refers to the numeric likelihood calculation = selection probabilities of coins chosen * success probabilities of coins chosen):

```
# sample of the final result
   coin_1_selection_probability coin_2_selection_probability coin_1_probability_of_success coin_2_probability_of_success     flip_1     flip_2 likelihood
1                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25  coin1 = H coin_1 = H        xyz
2                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_1 = H coin_1 = T        xyz
3                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_1 = T coin_1 = H        xyz
4                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_1 = T coin_1 = T        xyz
5                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_1 = H coin_2 = H        xyz
6                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_1 = H coin_2 = T        xyz
7                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_1 = T coin_2 = H        xyz
8                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_1 = T  coin_2= T        xyz
9                          0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25  coin_2= H coin_2 = H        xyz
10                         0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_2 = H coin_2 = T        xyz
11                         0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_2 = T coin_2 = H        xyz
12                         0.05                         0.95                          0.75                            0.25 coin_2 = T  coin_2= T        xyz
```

**I am not sure how to write the code for this problem.**

**Can someone please show me how I can correctly write the R code for my problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like homework, so what have you found with searching on points where you are stuck, and what have you tried that "didn't work" and what errors messages were emitted.

Comment: @irtfm: thank you for your reply! This is not homework.. I am actually planning on posting a question on mathoverflow about the EM algorithm and probability estimation.. and I want to post this question to serve as an example when I post on mathoverflow

Comment: I posted the progress I made, but I dont know how to continue

Comment: I'm still assuming I'm misunderstanding a bit of what you're trying to accomplish here.  Probability, when all other things remain consistent, does not change. if you flip a coin 1 time or 1000 times, assuming the coin is weighted evenly, your probability is still 50/50. When you want to know something like 2 coins getting HH 6 times in a row, then the probabilities change. Can you try to rephrase your question, so that I can better understand your goal here?

Comment: imagine there are two coins - coin1 has a p1 probability of being selected, coin2 has a p2 probability of being selected. coin1 has a q1 probability of being heads, coin2 has a q2 probability of being heads. For two coin flips ... for all possible values of p1, p2, q1, q2... I want to find out all possible results that could happen ... and the probability of these results.

Comment: In the first example, you include `p` and `1-p` which relates to the probability of which coin is being used. In the second example, you only look at the probably of each being successful. If the `p` is needed, please modify your second example to show two probabilities of how it would be used.

Comment: @cole: i made the changes

Comment: @stats_noob I requested the example to be modified to include an example calculation with the selection probability included. The example was deleted altogether. Maybe the edit got messed up somehow.

Comment: Hi everyone, OP here. I think I was able to solve this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424845/r-why-is-expand-grid-faster-than-for-loops ? Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, my own attempt to solve this problem - is my work correct?:

****Method 1:**** First, I used the expand.grid() function :

```
library(dplyr) 

t1 = Sys.time()
results <- expand.grid(probability_select_coin_1 = probability_select_coin_1_values, 
                       prob_head_coin_1 = prob_head_coin_1_values, 
                       prob_head_coin_2 = prob_head_coin_2_values, 
                       coin_selected_on_turn_1 = coin_selected_on_turn_1_values, 
                       coin_selected_on_turn_2 = coin_selected_on_turn_2_values, 
                       result_first_flip = result_first_flip_values, 
                       result_second_flip = result_second_flip_values)

# Calculate probability_select_coin_2 for each row
results$probability_select_coin_2 <- 1 - results$probability_select_coin_1


# calculate the likelihood 
results1 <- results %>%
  mutate(likelihood = case_when(
    coin_selected_on_turn_1 == "coin_1" & result_first_flip == "H" ~ probability_select_coin_1 * prob_head_coin_1,
    coin_selected_on_turn_1 == "coin_1" & result_first_flip == "T" ~ probability_select_coin_1 * (1 - prob_head_coin_1),
    coin_selected_on_turn_1 == "coin_2" & result_first_flip == "H" ~ probability_select_coin_2 * prob_head_coin_2,
    coin_selected_on_turn_1 == "coin_2" & result_first_flip == "T" ~ probability_select_coin_2 * (1 - prob_head_coin_2)
  ) * case_when(
    coin_selected_on_turn_2 == "coin_1" & result_second_flip == "H" ~ probability_select_coin_1 * prob_head_coin_1,
    coin_selected_on_turn_2 == "coin_1" & result_second_flip == "T" ~ probability_select_coin_1 * (1 - prob_head_coin_1),
    coin_selected_on_turn_2 == "coin_2" & result_second_flip == "H" ~ probability_select_coin_2 * prob_head_coin_2,
    coin_selected_on_turn_2 == "coin_2" & result_second_flip == "T" ~ probability_select_coin_2 * (1 - prob_head_coin_2)
  ))

t2 = Sys.time()

t2-t1
#Time difference of 1.268241 secs
```

****Method 2:****

```
Then, I tried to recreate this same code using a FOR LOOP:

    t1 <- Sys.time()
    # Initialize 
    results <- data.frame()
    
    # Loop for all combos
    for (probability_select_coin_1 in probability_select_coin_1_values) {
      probability_select_coin_2 <- 1 - probability_select_coin_1
      for (prob_head_coin_1 in prob_head_coin_1_values) {
        for (prob_head_coin_2 in prob_head_coin_2_values) {
          for (coin_selected_on_turn_1 in coin_selected_on_turn_1_values) {
            for (coin_selected_on_turn_2 in coin_selected_on_turn_2_values) {
              for (result_first_flip in result_first_flip_values) {
                for (result_second_flip in result_second_flip_values) {
                  # Store the current combination in the data frame
                  results <- rbind(results, c(probability_select_coin_1, probability_select_coin_2, prob_head_coin_1, prob_head_coin_2, coin_selected_on_turn_1, coin_selected_on_turn_2, result_first_flip, result_second_flip))
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    # Set names
    colnames(results) <- c("probability_select_coin_1", "probability_select_coin_2", "prob_head_coin_1", "prob_head_coin_2", "coin_selected_on_turn_1", "coin_selected_on_turn_2", "result_first_flip", "result_second_flip")
    
    
    results$probability_select_coin_1 = as.numeric(results$probability_select_coin_1)
    results$probability_select_coin_2 = as.numeric(results$probability_select_coin_2)
    results$prob_head_coin_1 = as.numeric(results$prob_head_coin_1)
    results$prob_head_coin_2 = as.numeric(results$prob_head_coin_2)
    
    # Calculate 
    results2 <- results %>%
      mutate(likelihood = case_when(
        coin_selected_on_turn_1 == "coin_1" & result_first_flip == "H" ~ probability_select_coin_1 * prob_head_coin_1,
        coin_selected_on_turn_1 == "coin_1" & result_first_flip == "T" ~ probability_select_coin_1 * (1 - prob_head_coin_1),
        coin_selected_on_turn_1 == "coin_2" & result_first_flip == "H" ~ probability_select_coin_2 * prob_head_coin_2,
        coin_selected_on_turn_1 == "coin_2" & result_first_flip == "T" ~ probability_select_coin_2 * (1 - prob_head_coin_2)
      ) * case_when(
        coin_selected_on_turn_2 == "coin_1" & result_second_flip == "H" ~ probability_select_coin_1 * prob_head_coin_1,
        coin_selected_on_turn_2 == "coin_1" & result_second_flip == "T" ~ probability_select_coin_1 * (1 - prob_head_coin_1),
        coin_selected_on_turn_2 == "coin_2" & result_second_flip == "H" ~ probability_select_coin_2 * prob_head_coin_2,
        coin_selected_on_turn_2 == "coin_2" & result_second_flip == "T" ~ probability_select_coin_2 * (1 - prob_head_coin_2)
      ))
    
     t1-t
    Time difference of 9.605949 mins
```